# can't access 2nd Router on my network

Tags: ip, router, gateway

I have a 2nd Router (192.168.1.71) connected to the Primary Router (192.168.1.1) use it for WIFI only purpose, but I can't access it (while connected to the WIFI), I am able to ping it. any ideas on what I can try?

when I go on 192.168.1.71 on chrome here is the message

```
This site can’t be reached
192.168.1.71 took too long to respond.
```

if you need any additional information let me know too.

[EDIT] I believe they might have the same gateway address of 192.168.1.1 
even when I unplug everything from my router, and connect directly from ethernet cable to the 2nd router I still have no luck connecting?

[EDIT 2] for people who want to **downvote** this post, please at least leave a comment as of why? so I know how to post a question better.

Comment: Not one of the down-voters, but you are missing info. Is the 2nd router static? Can you give models?  If it is truly a router, what port are you using to plug it in?

Comment: It's a netgear r8000, the 2nd router i believe is static, is there way to know for sure?  I am using it as a access point for wifi.  I plug it in not the primary port, but the other port.

Comment: The reason I want to get in to the 2nd router is to see if it also assign IP, b/c of constant ip conflict in my office.  And I can't see all the device connected in my primary router's dhcp server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot get to the management of the 2nd router, you should take it out, factory reset it, and then configure it properly.

As a general rule, you should not use a router as an access point. Routers provide more services than you need, and a few services that WILL cause issues.

If you are going to use a router as an access point, the minimum that you will need to do is:

1. Disabled DHCP (Or properly set up as parallel, but most SOHO devices won't support this.)
2. Set the IP to something else to prevent conflicts
3. Make sure you wireless channels are set to not overlap
4. Plug in your network to the LAN side of the router

Comment: yeah, I was contemplating to reset the router, but I didn't know what setting is on it, so I'm hesitating to do just that.  thanks